# OpenGL. Как исправить отображение текстуры

Tags: opengl

[image: Линии на дальней стене]

как исправить такое отображение текстуры на дальней стене, чтобы не было таких искажений?

Comment: Линии являются частью текстуры? Если да — включите mip-фильтрацию.

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему. Текущие описание "как исправить, чтобы не было таких искажений" совершенно неинформативно.